# NodeJS automatically click an element on a website

Tags: node.js, http, https, get, element

I need to make my code in node.js automatically click a button on a website (similar to auto login command but no input, just clicking a button). 
[Discord's verify phone button.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrkHd.png)

Any ideas?

EDIT: How can I do it with Puppeteer? Example/How to do it for my case?

Comment: To simulate activity it's better to use something like this https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer If you'd like to get example of code how to make it work in your case, update the question and tag me

Comment: @Grynets Done, I have updated it.

Answer (score 2):

So, to simulate user interactions with website, it's good to use Headless Browser.

And puppeteer is client for this headless browser.

To make some actions on target page you can use something like this:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('target url', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

  // Then you have to find element on page, which you'd like to click.
  // It could be done with your browser. The image would be later.
  // Or use JS selectors. We assume the easiest case to show the logic.
  // You selected the element and get path via browser.

  await page.click(<selector>);

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Documentation on [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.0/docs/api.md) and [click](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.0/docs/api.md#pageclickselector-options).
Just play around with API and find out the solution for your case.